# How to get the base url in jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Im creating a simple project by using jsp and servlet. I want to link the css in my jsp file. So any one can tell me the way to do this??

Comment: Why would you need a base URL for that? Why not using a relative path?

Comment: yes.. i need relative path or the base url!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<c:url var="baseUri" value="/" />
```

Note that this will give you a relative url to the context.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

provided that you have style.css file in folder "css" near your .jsp file. You don't need to know the base URL for that, this will work with any base URL that leads to your .jsp file.